# Can't read spaces in between words from mysql json php android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I'm trying to retrieve the total number of correct answers answered by the students from different countries.

I'm using `JSON` to link to my php then to my database. But i seems to can't read the spaces in between words. For example, the country name is `"Czech Republic"` in the database. However when i echo, it shows me `"Czech"`.

The `$country` in the php code is from the android studio, where i sent a url link `Config.LEADERSHIPBOARD_URL_ME + country;` to get connected to the database.

This is my php code:

```
<?php
    $country = $_GET['country'];

    require "conn.php";

    $sql_mcq = "SELECT * FROM mcqparticipator WHERE country = '".$country."'";
    $r_mcq = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_mcq);
    $result = array();

    $mcqCount = 0;

    if($r_mcq) 
    {   
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r_mcq))
        {   
            if(($row['correctAns'] == "1"))
            {
                $mcqCount++;
            }
        }

        array_push($result,array( 
        "McqCount"=>$mcqCount,
        "Country"=>$country));

        echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result)); 
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "No connection";       
    }

    $conn->close();
?>
```

And this is my code from `android studio`:

```
// Description: This method will generate a url and send a request
//              This method will call showJSON() method to start sending the response
private void getData(){

    loading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Please wait...","Fetching", false, false);
    url = Config.LEADERSHIPBOARD_URL_ME + country;

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            loading.dismiss();
            showJSON(response);

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Country in studio: " + country, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Country in database: " + dcountry, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Mcq count: " + McqCount, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No existing question", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

// Description: This method will generate a response using JSON via php.
// Retreive and compare the participants answer with the correct answer
public void showJSON(String response) {

    try{
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
        McqCount = collegeData.getString(Config.MCQ_COUNT);
        dcountry = collegeData.getString("Country");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Appreciate if someone could help me, thank you!

Comment: your code is vulnerable to **SQL Injection** - imagine someone sending a country like `'; DROP TABLE mcqparticipator; --`. use **parameterized statements** to protect yourself.

Comment: Okay, I will take note. Thank you.

Comment: Where do you see the lack of space ? The value you get from `$_GET['country']` ? If so, please show your HTML

Comment: PHP can "read" spaces alright. I think we're not seeing the part of the code that gets rid of it, because here you are not getting `$country` from database. What is the query string you are using here?